# Where to see Clion's Exception Messages

Tags: clion

I run the following code in CLion:

```
int main()
{
    char amessage [] = "oafaojfpa";
    char * pmessage = "oafaojfpa";
    char * apmessage = amessage;

    amessage[2]='X';
    *(pmessage+2)='X';

    printf(amessage);
    printf("\n");
    printf(pmessage);
    printf("\n");
    printf(apmessage);

    return(0);
}
```

The code `*(pmessage+2)='X';` should raise exceptions. However, the output is:

```
/Users/spacegoing/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/1ab7f406/1ab7f406/Debug/TCPL_Learn

Process finished with exit code 10
```

CLion only says exit code 10. But where can I view the exception message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only c++ code throws exceptions. In this case you are experiencing low level errors. You see a C/OS return value 10 which is BUS ERROR.

Bus errors are rare nowadays on x86 and occur when your processor cannot even attempt the memory access requested, typically:

- using a processor instruction with an address that does not satisfy its alignment requirements.
- modifying read only memory

Your pointer pmessage points to a string literal. This string is stored at read-only memory and trying to modify this memory leads to undefined behavior. It usually either segfaults or bus errors.